# How to connect Java client to WCF service using clientCredentialType="Basic"

Tags: java, .net, wcf, wcf-security, basic-authentication

I have to connect from a **Java client** to a **WCF Web Service** which has the following **binding configuration**:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingSecurity">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I'm using **JAX-WS**. Can you give me a code snippet showing how to set user name and password in a Java client?

I have tried this:

```
Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

but it did not work. I have also tried this:

```
Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://username:password@localhost:8090/MyService");
```

Still no success.

Thanks,
Rafal

Comment: +1 For a well worded and well formatted question.

Answer (score 2):

Oops! Sorry...

First solution works, but I have made a mistake in WCF service configuration. So basicaly if you have similar problem tired this:

```
Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
reqContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

Best regards,
Rafal

Comment: What mistake you did in WCF configuration. I am trying to call the WCF service using jax-ws client using the same approach, but I am getting 401 unathorized error, wherease same works through .net client